# MSSQL inner join with count for pagination

Tags: sql-server

I am joining 2 tables and returning the result with pagination for which I need COUNT.

```
 SQLCount = "SELECT COUNT(Documents.ID) AS CatCount FROM Documents INNER JOIN Videos ON Videos.ID Where Documents.Active = '1' and Video.Active = '1' "
 Set rsCount = dbConnection.Execute(SQLCount)
 strCatCount = rsCount("CatCount")
 rsCount.Close
 Set rsCount = Nothing

 SQLCat = "SELECT * FROM Documents INNER JOIN Videos Where Documents.Active = '1' and Video.Active = '1' Order By " & strResultOrder
 Set rsCat = dbConnection.Execute(SQLCat)
```

None of this works. Any ideas?

Comment: That is code, not query, debug your code may help you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe missing a **Group By** or join condition:

```
SELECT d.Id as Id, COUNT(d.ID) AS CatCount
FROM Documents d
INNER JOIN Videos v ON v.ID = d.Id
WHERE d.Active = '1' 
GROUP BY d.Id;
```

Comment: This gives...
Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

Comment: Look for PHP elsewhere. MSSQL means Msoft SQL which runs on Windows servers. Classic ASP and ASP.Net is used on Windows servers. This is not VB.

Comment: Using ID as a common denominator results in no results at all because the ID numbers are different in each table. I tried changing that to a field they both had in common and it resulted in a hugely fictitious count.